# Primitive Try/match handling in scala

Tags: scala

I wrote the following piece of code

```
 def info(): MyCaseClass = {
   Try {
     val fileSys = new File("somePath")
     MyCaseClass(fileSys.getTotalSpace, fileSys.getUsableSpace)
   } match {
      case Failure(f) => {
      logger.error(s"Could not read information:${f.getStackTrace}")
      MyCaseClass(0, 0)
    }
  case Success(s) => s
 }
}
```

Is there an even shorter way to deal with the fact that the file system operation could result in an exception so I handle it as above. Like can I not just somehow have to deal with failure case only. Like in case of Future exceptions, the future just does what it has to but for exceptions only we define `recover` and `recoverWith`. Something analogous is possible here?

Comment: If don't compose on `Try` or use it as result, rather directly use `try` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Try` has `recover` as well:

```
def info(): MyCaseClass = {
  (Try {
    val fileSys = new File("somePath")
    MyCaseClass(fileSys.getTotalSpace, fileSys.getUsableSpace)
  } recover {
    case f =>
      logger.error(s"Could not read information:${f.getStackTrace}")
      MyCaseClass(0, 0)
  }).get
}
```

Comment: But `Try#recover` returns `Try[MyCaseClass]`

Comment: @chunjef, good suggestion. Any idea of I tried fold/foldLeft if it will be dirtier or better?

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `try` instead of `Try`:

```
def info(): MyCaseClass = {
  try {
    val fileSys = new File("somePath")
    MyCaseClass(fileSys.getTotalSpace, fileSys.getUsableSpace)
  } catch {
     case f: Throwable => {
       logger.error(s"Could not read information:${f.getStackTrace}")
       MyCaseClass(0, 0)
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: This. `Try` job is to propagate the fact that there might be failure up to the caller, like checked exception with way less pain. But since failure is handled right there and there is a sensible default, there is no need for `Try`. I'd use `case NonFatal(f) =>`, btw

Answer (score 0):

`.getOrElse` seems to be what you are looking for:

```
def info(): MyCaseClass = {
  Try {
    val fileSys = new File("somePath")
    MyCaseClass(fileSys.getTotalSpace, fileSys.getUsableSpace)
  }.getOrElse({
    logger.error(s"Could not read information:${f.getStackTrace}")
    MyCaseClass(0, 0)
  })
}
```

Comment: but ``f`` is undefined now. Isn't it? It won't compile I guess